# How to disable a linkbutton to prevent multiple submits

Tags: javascript, linkbutton

I have HTML code like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="AddButton" runat="server" OnClick="AddPatientBtn_Click">
<span class="Normal">Add</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I find if we click 'Add' several times, it will add several patient records, so I want to change the code like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="AddButton" runat="server" OnClick="AddPatientBtn_Click" OnClientClick="return DisableButton(this)">
<span class="Normal">Add</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

js:

```
function DisableButton(button) {

document.all("AddButton").click;
button.href = "javascript:void(0);";
button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

}
```

But this doesn't work; I can still add many patient records.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of you!

I find that LinkButton may not have the disable attribute, it is a `<a>` in html page.

so I use another solution

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="AddButton" runat="server" OnClick="AddPatientBtn_Click" OnClientClick="return DisableButton()">
<span class="Normal">Add</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

js:

```
var pending = false;
function DisableButton() {if (pending) {
    alert("The new patient is being created. Please wait...");
    return false;
    }
    else {
         if (Page_ClientValidate(""))
         pending = true;
         return true;
     } 
}
```

Comment: what is Page_ClientValidate?

Comment: @singsuyash - It runs the client validation of the .net validators (requiredfieldvalidator etc.) and returns true if everything is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can just say

```
AddButton.Enabled = false;
```

in the code behind page

or you can write

```
document.getElementById("AddButton").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

var button = document.getElementById("AddButton");
button.setAttribute("disabled", "true");